# Is it possible to correct for violating the assumption of independence for nonparametric tests?

Tags: nonparametric, independence

Is it possible to correct for violating the assumption of independence for nonparametric tests?

I have a categorical independent variable and a categorical and binary dependent variable, and each subject was exposed to multiple levels of treatment. I have done some preliminary analysis with binary logistic regression and post-hoc chi-square tests, but I think these are inappropriate unless I can correct for my non-independent data. Info on this has been surprisingly difficult to find, and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may be having trouble finding info on this because you're looking for it under 'nonparametric tests'. This wouldn't usually be included under the (rather confusing) 'nonparametric' heading.

Logistic regression is sensible, but you'll need one of its extensions to deal with correlated outcomes, such as conditional (fixed-effects) logistic regression, random-effects logistic regression, or mixed-effects logistic regression. It's hard to say which is appropriate without knowing more about your data and the question(s) you wish to address.

Comment: In what sense is logistic regression nonparametric?  Just wondering...

Comment: I was trying to make the point that it isn't, or isn't normally thought of as such, but it's late and i'm too tired to word it well...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me!  I was worried that I had missed something.