# Correctly determine alpha for repeating statistical test in non-independent (interpolated) timeseries data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, independence

**Problem**

I have timeseries of measurements of which I also have determined the standard deviation of the noise. My goal is to determine whether or not the measurement is significantly different from **0** at every measured point with a net alpha of **a**.

**Explanation**

Now the timeseries are always of the same duration, but are not always sampled at the same interval. I have measurements that are sampled **K=n_i . k** (**n_i = 1 to n_max** ) times during the period of the measurement. Because of our setup however I always get **N** interpolated timepoints. **N > n_max . k**, so these **N** timepoints are never independent measurements.

If they were **N** independent measurements and I wanted them to be statistically different from **0** at every measured point with a net alpha of **a**, I would adjust the alpha to **a_adjusted = a^(1/N)**. So that testing **N** times leads to **a_adjusted^(N) = a**.

But how do I adjust **a** when I do **N** tests but there are really only **K** independent measurements? I still perform the test **N** times but since the outcome of the tests are not independent I think I should apply a correction for that. Should I just make **a_adjusted = a^(1/K)** or some ratio of **N** and **k**?

**Example**

I measure the output flow velocity of a cyclic pump over one pump cycle. Because of the way it works, the measuring apparatus I use can not output independent measurements. From the settings I can determine how many independent measurements are in the data, say 4.5 measurements. I also know how many timepoints are in the output of the apparatus, say 10 calculated time points. I also know the standard deviation of noise that is in one independent measurement, say 2. I then calculate the confidence interval for each timepoint. But I that is the 'incorrect' 95% confidence interval because it assumes the timepoints to be independent.

Example measurement:

[image: Dependent time series example]

These settings are not always the same for various reasons, but I would still like to test with the same 'net' alpha value for any setting. That way I can compare results between outputs with different settings. That is why I am trying to correct this alpha.

*Similar questions found on **Cross Validated**:*

[This question has a similar problem, except this person introduces the dependency himself and clusters the timeseries, seems more like averaging.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31574/computing-confidence-intervals-for-non-independent-data?rq=1)

[This question is very similar, but more broad. It asks 'is this correctable' instead of how to correct it in this specific situation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/is-it-possible-to-correct-for-violating-the-assumption-of-independence-for-nonpa?rq=1)

[This question also deals with dependent data, but in this case the different output points have a different number of measurements from which they are reconstructed. In my case this is equal for all points.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112751/correcting-for-multiple-testing-on-non-independent-sliding-windows?rq=1)

[This question is related, but focuses on correction for family wise error in multiple testing of dependent data.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181933/correcting-for-multiple-tests-in-datasets-with-auto-correlation-in-r?lq=1)

[This question is very similar too, except it wants to compare two timeseries which are interpolated / dependent. It was asked two years ago and has not received a comment or answer. Maybe ***Cross Validated*** is not the place to get answers about this.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92311/test-which-method-is-better-if-data-is-gathered-on-overlapping-time-windows-not?rq=1)